# hot to safe "isEnable" state of button in user defaults?

Tags: button, defaults

I have a button that adds a product to the wishlist. After it has been clicked i want it to have "isEnabled" state when user returns to the same product page again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a boolean to handle it? If not try it.

Comment: question is how to use user defaults

Comment: `UserDefaults` has methods to save and read Boolean values. Those are probably a good place to start.

Comment: thank you! where shall i write the code? inside the button function or in viewdidload?